# Proving $FP^2$ is transitive?

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry

Let $F$ be a field. A collineation of $F^3$, considered as the projective plane $FP^2$, is a permutation of lines and planes of $F^3$ that pass through the origin that preserves incidence. It's straightforward to check that any bijective linear operator on $F^3$ induces a collineation.

A collineation is said to have center $U$, where $U$ is a line, if it fixes $U$ and all planes containing it. Dually, it's said to have axis $V$, where $V$ is a plane, if it fixes $V$ and all lines in $V$.

We say that $FP^2$ is $(U, V)$-transitive if for any lines $U_1, U_2$ that are not in $V$, that are distinct from $U$, and that are coplanar with $U$, there is a collineation that has center $U$, axis $V$, and maps $U_1\mapsto U_2$. I want to show that $FP^2$ is $(U, V)$ transitive for any line $U$ and plane $V$.

First, I assume that $U\leq V$. Then, there's a bijective linear operator that acts as the identity on $V$ and sends $U_1\mapsto U_2$. This obviously has axis $V$, but I'm not sure how to prove nicely that this linear operator also fixes all planes through $U$. Is there a quick proof of this fact?

Second, there's the case where $U$ is not a subspace of $V$. In this case, I'm not sure how to build a bijective linear operator as required. There are actually many choices that fix $U$ and send $U_1\mapsto U_2$ (since we can scale along lines), and I still need to pick a third basis vector and its image so that $V$ and all its lines are fixed. Is there a nice way to do this? Note that $F$ is an arbitrary field, so I'm not sure how much I have to work with.

Comment: You probably also want to require $U_1$ and $U_2$ to be distinct from $U$. (This is not implied by "coplanar with $U$" in my understanding of the word "coplanar".)

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Here is a sketch of a solution. Pretend that $V$ is the line at infinity (this can always be ensured by an application of a projective transformation). Then you are looking for an invertible affine transformation of the plane $F^2$ to itself which fixes $U$ and sends $U_1$ to $U_2$. This is just a homothety centered at $U$.

Comment: Hmm, how do you translate that into the language of linear algebra?

Comment: Well, you know that projective transformations are collineations, right? (Sometimes there are other collineations as well, but you don't need those here.) And projective endomorphisms of $FP^2$ that fix the line at infinity can be identified with affine endomorphisms of $F^2$.

Comment: Oh, so we're using the isomorphism between $FP^2$ and the extension of $F^2$ by points and a line at infinity?

Comment: Yes, we are. (It is easy to prove.)

Comment: Hmm, it's easy to see when $F=\mathbb R$, but in other cases, how do we make sure that lines in $F^3$ intersect planes?

Comment: In the same way as when $F = \mathbb R$. There is nothing used about the ground field in this.